# Combine two or more compressed files

Tags: tar, gzip

I have 2 gz files those I need to merge into one -- that is to say I want to combine two .gz files into one such that when I extract the combined file I get a single file containing the concatenation of the original input files.

```
time join <(zcat r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz) <(zcat r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz)
```

The above statement is not working as expected. I am using 3 commands to do the needful.

```
gunzip r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz 
gunzip r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz 
tar -zcvf combined.tar.gz r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00 r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00
```

and then concatenating the files together when I extract them to produce the output I want.

Is there any way to do this in 1 statement?

Comment: When the final file extracted, do you want two files extracted, or a single file which is the concatenation of the two files?

Comment: single gz file.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. When the final compressed file is extracted, do you want `r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00` and `r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00`, or do you want a single uncompressed file which is those two files concatenated together?

Comment: How about this `cat r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz > final.gz`?

Comment: final.gz will have 2 files in it. I need single uncompressed file that is concatenation of those two files.

Comment: @shantanuo I have tried to clarify your wording in your question based on your comments. If I've botched it (or you can think of a clearer way to describe what you want) please fix as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly what Quanta posted in the comments works -- at least on my Mac!

```
$ echo abc > foo
$ echo cba > bar
$ gzip foo
$ gzip bar
$ cat foo.gz bar.gz > baz.gz
$ gunzip baz.gz 
$ cat baz 
abc
cba
$
```

I am somewhat disturbed, yet also impressed.

Comment: Yup, it's [intentional](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gzip.1.html#contenttoc4).

Comment: I find such behavior disturbing... but I guess someone had the same use case as @shantanuo

Answer (score 7):

I guess you mean:

`zcat r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz| gzip -9 > joined.gz`

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple compressed files `.gz` and you need to combine them into one file, you can use `tar` directly to do so. No need to uncompress and then compress them again.

You can try this:

```
tar cvf combined.gz.tar r_TR1_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz r_TR2_2012-05-28-08-10-00.gz
```

However, you will get a file with extension `.gz.tar` as opposed to the known `.tar.gz`. To uncompress the file, you can try:

```
tar -xavf combined.gz.tar
```

The option -a is useful here (from `man tar`):

```
-a, --auto-compress
       use archive suffix to determine the compression program
```